# using set_userdata() in codeigniter replaces the previous session value

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I am trying to merge previous session value with current session value but unfortunately the last session are destroy when i try to merge both value.

this is the code i use for merge session array.

```
$sess=$this->session->userdata('sesse');
    $covr_wrap_mil=array();
                $covr_wrp=$this->session->userdata('bar');              
                $mil=array('miluna_products'=>$milunaid,'total_price'=>$totalprice);            
                $covr_wrap_mil[]=array_merge($covr_wrp,$mil);

                    if(isset($sess)  && !empty($sess)):

                        $oldses=$this->session->userdata('sesse');                      
                                $oldses=array_merge($oldses,$covr_wrap_mil);                            
                                $this->session->set_userdata('sesse',$covr_wrap_mil);

                    else:

                        $this->session->set_userdata('sesse',$covr_wrap_mil);   

                    endif;
```

currently i am getting this array

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [style_id] => 308
            [wrap] => Array
                (
                    [285] => 285
                )

            [cover] => Array
                (
                    [307] => 307
                )

            [miluna_products] => a:2:{s:6:"322%14";s:30:"a:1:{i:0;s:12:"100_2102.jpg";}";s:7:"323%268";s:35:"a:1:{i:0;s:17:"1449004825736.gif";}";}
            [total_price] => 282
        )

)
```

but i want to merge newly array with previous array like this.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [style_id] => 308
            [wrap] => Array
                (
                    [285] => 285
                )

            [cover] => Array
                (
                    [307] => 307
                )

            [miluna_products] => a:2:{s:6:"322%14";s:30:"a:1:{i:0;s:12:"100_2102.jpg";}";s:7:"323%268";s:35:"a:1:{i:0;s:17:"1449004825736.gif";}";}
            [total_price] => 282
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [style_id] => 309
            [wrap] => Array
                (
                    [275] => 275
                )

            [cover] => Array
                (
                    [377] => 377
                )

            [miluna_products] => a:2:{s:6:"322%14";s:30:"a:1:{i:0;s:12:"100_2102.jpg";}";s:7:"323%268";s:35:"a:1:{i:0;s:17:"1449004825736.gif";}";}
            [total_price] => 282
        )

)
```

not understand where is the problem. any help would highly appreciated.

Comment: array_merge is working but again your storing session  only $covr_wrap_mil   this what problem here so you have to set the session  $oldses  to use in last line instead of $covr_wrap_mil like this $oldses=$this->session->userdata('sesse');                      
                                $oldses=array_merge($oldses,$covr_wrap_mil);                            
                                $this->session->set_userdata('sesse', $oldses);

Comment: thank u  @JYoThI for reply u are right.  i use $this->session->set_userdata('sesse', $oldses); but it not working.

Comment: you must store the current session first into an array before you set new value to the session variables and after that merge the new session values to your previous array.

Answer (score 1):

You have merged array but you **missed** to set session data with merged array,

**Change**

> Here you are overwriting session with `$covr_wrap_mil` data 
>          instead of merged array `$oldses` data so it was replacing old session  data

```
$oldses=$this->session->userdata('sesse');                               
$oldses=array_merge($oldses,$covr_wrap_mil);  
/* Here you are overwriting session with covr_wrap_mil data 
   instead of merged array data so it was replacing old session   
   data
*/                        
$this->session->set_userdata('sesse',$covr_wrap_mil);
```

**To**

```
$oldses=$this->session->userdata('sesse');                               
$oldses=array_merge($oldses,$covr_wrap_mil);                          
$this->session->set_userdata('sesse', $oldses);
```

**Finally It would look like below**

```
 $sess=$this->session->userdata('sesse');

 $covr_wrap_mil=array();
 $covr_wrp=$this->session->userdata('bar');              
 $mil=array('miluna_products'=>$milunaid,'total_price'=>$totalprice);            
 $covr_wrap_mil[]=array_merge($covr_wrp,$mil);

 if(!empty($sess)):   
     $oldses=$sess;                      
     $oldses=array_merge($oldses,$covr_wrap_mil);                            
     $this->session->set_userdata('sesse',$oldses);   
 else:
     $this->session->set_userdata('sesse',$covr_wrap_mil);   
 endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right. Only change one line

```
 $oldses=$this->session->userdata('sesse');                      
 $oldses=array_merge($oldses,$covr_wrap_mil);                            
 $this->session->set_userdata('sesse',$oldses);
```

to  set mergred array to session you have to store value of $oldses not of $covr_wrap_mil

Answer (score 0):

use `array_push()` instead of `array_merge()`.In `array_merge()` keys are updated with the newer values and you lost earlier session values

So your code will be

```
$sess=$this->session->userdata('sesse');
$covr_wrap_mil=array();
            $covr_wrp=$this->session->userdata('bar');              
            $mil=array('miluna_products'=>$milunaid,'total_price'=>$totalprice);            
            $covr_wrap_mil[]=array_merge($covr_wrp,$mil);

                if(isset($sess)  && !empty($sess)):
                 $older_session=array(); //crate new array
                 $oldses=$this->session->userdata('sesse');                      
                 array_push($older_session,$oldses,$covr_wrap_mil);
               /*update session with $older_session*/                           
                 $this->session->set_userdata('sesse',$older_session);

                else:

                    $this->session->set_userdata('sesse',$covr_wrap_mil);   

                endif;
```